# How can I solve Server Error in '/' Application Index has not been initialized?

Tags: sitecore-client, azure, sitecore-api, azure-search

If I access my home page, show error like this :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Index has not been initialized.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Index has not been initialized.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

[image]

The error above occurs when I restart Porta Azure like this :

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Before I restarted the azure portal, there was no error

Comment: @Mark Gibbons I found this problem this afternoon. after I restarted my server, and accessing the homepage the error appeared. but if I access another page, it can

Comment: It's the same error as the one I linked so I don't see how its any different?